# dmesg: pci BAR 7: can't assign io

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, pci, dmesg, hot-plug

I have VMware virtual machine running Debian Wheezy. I have compiled my own kernel 3.14. I have noticed `dmesg` is flooded with messages `pci BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)`.

I have no idea what these messages mean. The VM seems to be running OK, I don't see any problems. Nevertheless, I am bothered by these error messages, and I would be happy if I could get rid of them.

Could somebody please explain

**1) what do these messages mean**

**2) how can I get rid of them**

```
...
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices
ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
pci 0000:00:15.3: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.4: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 07] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.5: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 08] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.6: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 09] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.7: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 0a] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.3: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 0e] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.4: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 0f] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.5: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 10] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.6: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 11] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.7: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 12] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.3: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 16] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.4: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 17] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.5: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 18] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.6: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 19] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.7: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 1a] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.2: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 1d] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.3: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 1e] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.4: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 1f] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.5: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 20] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.6: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 21] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.7: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 22] add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.3: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.4: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.5: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.6: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:15.7: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.3: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.4: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.5: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.6: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:16.7: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.3: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.4: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.5: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.6: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:17.7: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.2: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.3: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.4: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.5: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.6: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:18.7: res[7]=[io  0x1000-0x0fff] get_res_add_size add_size 1000
pci 0000:00:0f.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xc0000000-0xc0007fff pref]
pci 0000:00:15.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.2: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:18.2: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:17.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:16.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.7: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.6: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.5: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.4: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:15.3: BAR 7: can't assign io (size 0x1000)
pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
pci 0000:00:11.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
pci 0000:00:11.0:   bridge window [io  0x2000-0x3fff]
pci 0000:00:11.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd1900000-0xd23fffff]
pci 0000:00:11.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdc400000-0xdc9fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:03:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xd4400000-0xd440ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:15.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
pci 0000:00:15.0:   bridge window [io  0x4000-0x4fff]
pci 0000:00:15.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd2400000-0xd24fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4400000-0xd44fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.1: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
pci 0000:00:15.1:   bridge window [io  0x8000-0x8fff]
pci 0000:00:15.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd2800000-0xd28fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd4800000-0xd48fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.2: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
pci 0000:00:15.2:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
pci 0000:00:15.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd2c00000-0xd2cfffff]
pci 0000:00:15.2:   bridge window [mem 0xdcb00000-0xdcbfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.3: PCI bridge to [bus 06]
pci 0000:00:15.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd3000000-0xd30fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.3:   bridge window [mem 0xdcd00000-0xdcdfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.4: PCI bridge to [bus 07]
pci 0000:00:15.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd3400000-0xd34fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.4:   bridge window [mem 0xdcf00000-0xdcffffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.5: PCI bridge to [bus 08]
pci 0000:00:15.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd3800000-0xd38fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.5:   bridge window [mem 0xdd100000-0xdd1fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.6: PCI bridge to [bus 09]
pci 0000:00:15.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd3c00000-0xd3cfffff]
pci 0000:00:15.6:   bridge window [mem 0xdd300000-0xdd3fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:15.7: PCI bridge to [bus 0a]
pci 0000:00:15.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd4000000-0xd40fffff]
pci 0000:00:15.7:   bridge window [mem 0xdd500000-0xdd5fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:0b:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xd4500000-0xd450ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:16.0: PCI bridge to [bus 0b]
pci 0000:00:16.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
pci 0000:00:16.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd2500000-0xd25fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4500000-0xd45fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.1: PCI bridge to [bus 0c]
pci 0000:00:16.1:   bridge window [io  0x9000-0x9fff]
pci 0000:00:16.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd2900000-0xd29fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd4900000-0xd49fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.2: PCI bridge to [bus 0d]
pci 0000:00:16.2:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
pci 0000:00:16.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd2d00000-0xd2dfffff]
pci 0000:00:16.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd4b00000-0xd4bfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.3: PCI bridge to [bus 0e]
pci 0000:00:16.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd3100000-0xd31fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd4d00000-0xd4dfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.4: PCI bridge to [bus 0f]
pci 0000:00:16.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd3500000-0xd35fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd4f00000-0xd4ffffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.5: PCI bridge to [bus 10]
pci 0000:00:16.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd3900000-0xd39fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd5100000-0xd51fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.6: PCI bridge to [bus 11]
pci 0000:00:16.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd3d00000-0xd3dfffff]
pci 0000:00:16.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd5300000-0xd53fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:16.7: PCI bridge to [bus 12]
pci 0000:00:16.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd4100000-0xd41fffff]
pci 0000:00:16.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd5500000-0xd55fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.0: PCI bridge to [bus 13]
pci 0000:00:17.0:   bridge window [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
pci 0000:00:17.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd2600000-0xd26fffff]
pci 0000:00:17.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4600000-0xd46fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.1: PCI bridge to [bus 14]
pci 0000:00:17.1:   bridge window [io  0xa000-0xafff]
pci 0000:00:17.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd2a00000-0xd2afffff]
pci 0000:00:17.1:   bridge window [mem 0xdca00000-0xdcafffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.2: PCI bridge to [bus 15]
pci 0000:00:17.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
pci 0000:00:17.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd2e00000-0xd2efffff]
pci 0000:00:17.2:   bridge window [mem 0xdcc00000-0xdccfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.3: PCI bridge to [bus 16]
pci 0000:00:17.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd3200000-0xd32fffff]
pci 0000:00:17.3:   bridge window [mem 0xdce00000-0xdcefffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.4: PCI bridge to [bus 17]
pci 0000:00:17.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd3600000-0xd36fffff]
pci 0000:00:17.4:   bridge window [mem 0xdd000000-0xdd0fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.5: PCI bridge to [bus 18]
pci 0000:00:17.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd3a00000-0xd3afffff]
pci 0000:00:17.5:   bridge window [mem 0xdd200000-0xdd2fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.6: PCI bridge to [bus 19]
pci 0000:00:17.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd3e00000-0xd3efffff]
pci 0000:00:17.6:   bridge window [mem 0xdd400000-0xdd4fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:17.7: PCI bridge to [bus 1a]
pci 0000:00:17.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd4200000-0xd42fffff]
pci 0000:00:17.7:   bridge window [mem 0xdd600000-0xdd6fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.0: PCI bridge to [bus 1b]
pci 0000:00:18.0:   bridge window [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
pci 0000:00:18.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd2700000-0xd27fffff]
pci 0000:00:18.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4700000-0xd47fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.1: PCI bridge to [bus 1c]
pci 0000:00:18.1:   bridge window [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
pci 0000:00:18.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd2b00000-0xd2bfffff]
pci 0000:00:18.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd4a00000-0xd4afffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.2: PCI bridge to [bus 1d]
pci 0000:00:18.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd2f00000-0xd2ffffff]
pci 0000:00:18.2:   bridge window [mem 0xd4c00000-0xd4cfffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.3: PCI bridge to [bus 1e]
pci 0000:00:18.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd3300000-0xd33fffff]
pci 0000:00:18.3:   bridge window [mem 0xd4e00000-0xd4efffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.4: PCI bridge to [bus 1f]
pci 0000:00:18.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd3700000-0xd37fffff]
pci 0000:00:18.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd5000000-0xd50fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.5: PCI bridge to [bus 20]
pci 0000:00:18.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd3b00000-0xd3bfffff]
pci 0000:00:18.5:   bridge window [mem 0xd5200000-0xd52fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.6: PCI bridge to [bus 21]
pci 0000:00:18.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd3f00000-0xd3ffffff]
pci 0000:00:18.6:   bridge window [mem 0xd5400000-0xd54fffff 64bit pref]
pci 0000:00:18.7: PCI bridge to [bus 22]
pci 0000:00:18.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd4300000-0xd43fffff]
pci 0000:00:18.7:   bridge window [mem 0xd5600000-0xd56fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [mem 0x000cc000-0x000cffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0xc0000000-0xfebfffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [io  0x0d00-0xfeff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0x2000-0x3fff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xd1900000-0xd23fffff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xdc400000-0xdc9fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 4 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 5 [mem 0x000cc000-0x000cffff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 6 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 7 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 8 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 9 [mem 0xc0000000-0xfebfffff]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 10 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
pci_bus 0000:02: resource 11 [io  0x0d00-0xfeff]
pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0x4000-0x4fff]
pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xd2400000-0xd24fffff]
pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xd4400000-0xd44fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io  0x8000-0x8fff]
pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xd2800000-0xd28fffff]
pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xd4800000-0xd48fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:05: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xd2c00000-0xd2cfffff]
pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xdcb00000-0xdcbfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:06: resource 1 [mem 0xd3000000-0xd30fffff]
pci_bus 0000:06: resource 2 [mem 0xdcd00000-0xdcdfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:07: resource 1 [mem 0xd3400000-0xd34fffff]
pci_bus 0000:07: resource 2 [mem 0xdcf00000-0xdcffffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:08: resource 1 [mem 0xd3800000-0xd38fffff]
pci_bus 0000:08: resource 2 [mem 0xdd100000-0xdd1fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:09: resource 1 [mem 0xd3c00000-0xd3cfffff]
pci_bus 0000:09: resource 2 [mem 0xdd300000-0xdd3fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0a: resource 1 [mem 0xd4000000-0xd40fffff]
pci_bus 0000:0a: resource 2 [mem 0xdd500000-0xdd5fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0b: resource 0 [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
pci_bus 0000:0b: resource 1 [mem 0xd2500000-0xd25fffff]
pci_bus 0000:0b: resource 2 [mem 0xd4500000-0xd45fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0c: resource 0 [io  0x9000-0x9fff]
pci_bus 0000:0c: resource 1 [mem 0xd2900000-0xd29fffff]
pci_bus 0000:0c: resource 2 [mem 0xd4900000-0xd49fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0d: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
pci_bus 0000:0d: resource 1 [mem 0xd2d00000-0xd2dfffff]
pci_bus 0000:0d: resource 2 [mem 0xd4b00000-0xd4bfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0e: resource 1 [mem 0xd3100000-0xd31fffff]
pci_bus 0000:0e: resource 2 [mem 0xd4d00000-0xd4dfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:0f: resource 1 [mem 0xd3500000-0xd35fffff]
pci_bus 0000:0f: resource 2 [mem 0xd4f00000-0xd4ffffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:10: resource 1 [mem 0xd3900000-0xd39fffff]
pci_bus 0000:10: resource 2 [mem 0xd5100000-0xd51fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:11: resource 1 [mem 0xd3d00000-0xd3dfffff]
pci_bus 0000:11: resource 2 [mem 0xd5300000-0xd53fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:12: resource 1 [mem 0xd4100000-0xd41fffff]
pci_bus 0000:12: resource 2 [mem 0xd5500000-0xd55fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:13: resource 0 [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
pci_bus 0000:13: resource 1 [mem 0xd2600000-0xd26fffff]
pci_bus 0000:13: resource 2 [mem 0xd4600000-0xd46fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:14: resource 0 [io  0xa000-0xafff]
pci_bus 0000:14: resource 1 [mem 0xd2a00000-0xd2afffff]
pci_bus 0000:14: resource 2 [mem 0xdca00000-0xdcafffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:15: resource 0 [io  0xe000-0xefff]
pci_bus 0000:15: resource 1 [mem 0xd2e00000-0xd2efffff]
pci_bus 0000:15: resource 2 [mem 0xdcc00000-0xdccfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:16: resource 1 [mem 0xd3200000-0xd32fffff]
pci_bus 0000:16: resource 2 [mem 0xdce00000-0xdcefffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:17: resource 1 [mem 0xd3600000-0xd36fffff]
pci_bus 0000:17: resource 2 [mem 0xdd000000-0xdd0fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:18: resource 1 [mem 0xd3a00000-0xd3afffff]
pci_bus 0000:18: resource 2 [mem 0xdd200000-0xdd2fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:19: resource 1 [mem 0xd3e00000-0xd3efffff]
pci_bus 0000:19: resource 2 [mem 0xdd400000-0xdd4fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1a: resource 1 [mem 0xd4200000-0xd42fffff]
pci_bus 0000:1a: resource 2 [mem 0xdd600000-0xdd6fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1b: resource 0 [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
pci_bus 0000:1b: resource 1 [mem 0xd2700000-0xd27fffff]
pci_bus 0000:1b: resource 2 [mem 0xd4700000-0xd47fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1c: resource 0 [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
pci_bus 0000:1c: resource 1 [mem 0xd2b00000-0xd2bfffff]
pci_bus 0000:1c: resource 2 [mem 0xd4a00000-0xd4afffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1d: resource 1 [mem 0xd2f00000-0xd2ffffff]
pci_bus 0000:1d: resource 2 [mem 0xd4c00000-0xd4cfffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1e: resource 1 [mem 0xd3300000-0xd33fffff]
pci_bus 0000:1e: resource 2 [mem 0xd4e00000-0xd4efffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:1f: resource 1 [mem 0xd3700000-0xd37fffff]
pci_bus 0000:1f: resource 2 [mem 0xd5000000-0xd50fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:20: resource 1 [mem 0xd3b00000-0xd3bfffff]
pci_bus 0000:20: resource 2 [mem 0xd5200000-0xd52fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:21: resource 1 [mem 0xd3f00000-0xd3ffffff]
pci_bus 0000:21: resource 2 [mem 0xd5400000-0xd54fffff 64bit pref]
pci_bus 0000:22: resource 1 [mem 0xd4300000-0xd43fffff]
pci_bus 0000:22: resource 2 [mem 0xd5600000-0xd56fffff 64bit pref]
```

Following is the identification of the device with `lspci`

```
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d3000000-d30fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000dcd00000-00000000dcdfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: VMware PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

## **UPDATE**

actually, dmesg contains over 550 lines of (debug) logs related to PCI.
I have pasted the relevant part [here](http://pastebin.com/SrJwCHir)

## **How can I get rid of these logs?**

They are not useful, and are just flooding my logs

Comment: Looked into it a little bit and [it looks like the error message is saying it can't allocate I/O buffers in memory for some device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration). Beyond that I'm not too sure what it means or what to do. I would probably cross-reference that PCI address listed in `dmesg` with those out of `lspci` to see if you can guess what the specific device is in the hopes that might push you further in the right direction.

Comment: @Bratchley - `lspci -v` shows: `00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)`. I will update my question with the full output (`lspci -vvv`). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Also, might be worth knowing if you get the error when you boot from a stock kernel. It might be a regression in the upstream kernel. Normally projects hold off on adopting a new kernel until it seems stable or they backport fixes to a particular kernel, it's possible that's what was lost here. If it is, you may just ignore it since it seems like it would only affect PCI devices coming from that particular root port. By the time it becomes an issue (probably from a HW change) you'll probably be on a later kernel.

Comment: @ Bratchley - I don't get these errors when I boot stock kernel 3.2. I could not find stock kernel 3.14 to try that one. Do you understand what these errors mean? What are these `BARs` ?

Comment: The "BAR" thing is explained by the link in my first comment. Full name is "Base Address Register" which seems to be just the range of memory space the device uses to communicate with the rest of the system.

Comment: Can you try `pci=nocrs` at kernel command line while booting ?

Comment: @SHW - `pci=nocrs` only gets rid of 20 lines, out of 550

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me as if you are experiencing a bug related to memory allocation for PCI bus data throughput, despite the fact you are running in a VM. While I am not familiar with VMWare, I suspect there may be a PCI emulation or memory allocation-related setting you could tweak to fix it.

The forum thread referenced at the end of this post suggests that a similar problem might be fixed by disabling ACPI, though I can't vouch for the accuracy of said thread.

I suspect (though I have no information to back this up, so take it with a grain of salt) that it may have something to do with the architecture you are emulating. If you're emulating 32 bit x86, I might suggest trying to emulate the 64 bit version of the same software, and testing if it occurs there too.

As for removing the log, I believe that can easily be done using `dmesg -C`, or perhaps (if you'd like to automate it) setting up a cron task to execute the aforementioned task every hour.

Related thread: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/pci-i-o-mem-issues-913960/

Answer (score 0):

It is related to memory allocation for PCI bus data throughput. 
Please enable the Traffic Shaping option in the vSwitch throughthe vSphere Client.

I have tried this and works fine for me.

Comment: how can Traffic shaping (QoS) settings on vSwitch have anything to do with PCI bus data throughput on my virtual machine ?